# Adding firestore "get" result to the $scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-material

So I have this code to make the firestore response an array of objects which then I set the `$scope.dbCountryFromFirestore` to be equal to that array.

```
db.collection('country').get().then((snapshot) => {
        var dataToScope= [];
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
            dataToScope.push(doc.data());
        });
        $scope.dbCountryFromFirestore = dataToScope;
    })
```

Thing is this doesn't seem to work, and I can't understand why.

Making a local `getJSON` request on the other hand, works.

```
$.getJSON("databases/dbCurrency.json", function(json) {
        var arr = new Array();
        $.each(json, function (i, item) {
            arr.push(json[i].cc);
        })


        $scope.dbCurrency = arr;
    });
```

Comment: Use angular `$http` instead of `$.getJSON`. Otherwise since you are changing scope outside of angular context  and need call `$apply` to tell angular to run a digest

Comment: @charlietfl and how would I do it in the firestore one?

Comment: Use angularFire module. Simplifies getting data and also takes care of managing digests